# Read CSV file on protected zip

Tags: csv, go, passwords, zip

I have link like this: https://storage.googleapis.com/data/test_file.csv.zip
the content is one csv file on the protected zip with password. How can I read data from the csv?

I have try this but its error

```
func ReadCSVZIPFromURL(fileURL string) (data [][]string, err error) {
    resp, err := http.Get(fileURL)
    if err != nil {
        return data, errors.AddTrace(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    r, err := zip.OpenReader(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer r.Close()

    for _, file := range r.File {
        if file.IsEncrypted() {
            file.SetPassword("password")
        }
        reader := csv.NewReader(file)

        data, err := reader.ReadAll()
    }

    return data, nil
}
```

Comment: What's the error? And what package do you use for zip handling (the `zip` package in your code).

Comment: error: cannot use resp.Body (type io.ReadCloser) as type string in argument to zip.OpenReader.
using golang zip

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/yeka/zip#NewReader

Comment: There's not ZIP file at the provided URL.

Comment: its just a sample link of zip. the real link just can be acces by internal connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solve the problem, this the solve. the idea is we copy the byte to zip reader, and we will get the ioReader, the we we read ioReader use csv library.
to encrypt and decrypt data using password we use this library "github.com/alexmullins/zip"

```
func GetCSVFromZipURL(ctx context.Context, fileURL, filePassword string) (ioReader io.Reader, err error) {
    span, ctx := tracer.StartSpanFromContext(ctx)
    defer span.Finish()

    resp, err := http.Get(fileURL)
    if err != nil {
        return ioReader, errors.AddTrace(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}

    _, err = io.Copy(buf, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return ioReader, errors.AddTrace(err)
    }

    b := bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes())
    r, err := zip.NewReader(b, int64(b.Len()))
    if err != nil {
        return ioReader, errors.AddTrace(err)
    }

    for _, f := range r.File {
        if f.IsEncrypted() {
            f.SetPassword(filePassword)
        }
        ioReader, err = f.Open()
        if err != nil {
            return ioReader, errors.AddTrace(err)
        }

        return ioReader, nil
    }

    return ioReader, nil
}

func getUserBenefitListFromCSV(ioReader io.Reader) (userBenefitList []UserBenefit, err error) {
    reader := csv.NewReader(ioReader)

    row := 1
    for {
        csvRowsStr, err := reader.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return userBenefitList, errors.AddTrace(err)
        }

        // check if 1st row (header), skip
        if row == 1 {
            row++
            continue
        }

        if len(csvRowsStr) > 0 {
            userID, err := strconv.ParseInt(csvRowsStr[0], 10, 64)
            if err != nil {
                return userBenefitList, errors.AddTrace(err)
            }

            catalogID := 0
            if len(csvRowsStr) > 1 {
                catalogID, err = strconv.ParseInt(csvRowsStr[1], 10, 64)
                if err != nil {
                    return userBenefitList, errors.AddTrace(err)
                }
            }

            userBenefitTemp := UserBenefit{
                UserID:    userID,
                CatalogID: catalogID,
            }

            userBenefitList = append(userBenefitList, userBenefitTemp)
        }
    }

    return userBenefitList, nil
}
```